# BeautifulSoup4 find all tags with attribute begins with a string in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

How can I use beautifulsoup to find all tags with attributes that begins with some string?

The following doesn't seem to work :(

```
soup.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('^com')})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work as expected... I think It doesn't work in your case is because your example is wrong. Because normally a `href` tag doesn't begin with `com` they usually begin with either `http` or `https`

Running your example against your own question, it works as expected:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416106/beautifulsoup4-find-all-tags-with-attribute-begins-with-a-string-in-python")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)

http = soup.find('a', {'href':re.compile('^http')})
print http
```

Produces:

```
<a data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:6 })" href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com">chat</a>
```

And if you replace `^http` with `^https` you'll get a `a` tag with a `href` that begins with `https`

*Note: I used the `find()` method for simplicity*

Comment: gotcha... it did work! I forgot to add the "#"... the href was "#com.xxx.xxx"

Comment: I do have a related question, when I print my soup, there was only 6 matches with string "<a name=", but when the actual html has 10 matches... why did the soup failed to get all the html?